# I have a variable value in lower case and the same value is in one of the dictionary keys how do I fulfill the condition

Tags: python, string, dictionary, character

i have document_title variable value with lowercase letters and same value is in the dic keys with upercase letter

```
TITLE_MAP = {
    'AUS Marketing Consent': "DOCUMENT_TYPE_MARKETING_CONSENT",
    'Consent & History': "DOCUMENT_TYPE_CONSENT",
}

document_title = 'aus marketing consent'
```

if i do this won't work with me

```
if document_title in TITLE_MAP.keys():
   return True
```

I want to fulfill the condition even with the difference

Comment: Normalize all the keys in your dictionary (e.g., make them all upper case or all lower case). Then normalize the key before checking if it is in the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `casefold` method to do string comparison. Since you want to apply it to all the keys, you can use a list comprehension.

```
if document_title.casefold() in [x.casefold() for x in TITLE_MAP.keys()]:
    print(True)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Use `.casefold` is the correct approach, although, you should *create a new, normalized dictionary* and use that. Also, you should stop using `.keys()` needlessly

Comment: Hi, I'm interested to understand why this approach would be better. Why would you create a new dictionary instead of using the existing one ? Also why is it bad to call .keys() ? My understanding is that your method would be better if you want to reuse it a lot, but if it's only a one time use, isn't it overkill ? I might be wrong. Thank you.

Comment: My assumption is that this dictionary will be used multiple times in the same way. It's not "bad" to call `.keys()`, it's just redundant and unnecessary in this case.

Comment: All right, that's what I thought. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
if document_title.upper() in TITLE_MAP.key():
   return True
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's overkill but you can try this solution :

```py
if document_title.lower() in {k.lower() for k in TITLE_MAP.keys()}:
    print(True)
```

It lowers every keys from your dictionnary

Answer (score 0):

The two strings must be in the same case. You have to convert all keys to lowercase. Try the code below

```
TITLE_MAP = {
    'AUS Marketing Consent': "DOCUMENT_TYPE_MARKETING_CONSENT",
    'Consent & History': "DOCUMENT_TYPE_CONSENT",
}

TITLE_MAP = {k.lower(): v for k, v in TITLE_MAP.items()}

document_title = 'aus marketing consent'

if document_title.lower() in TITLE_MAP:
    print(True)
```